# Get CSS position property of element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have this `<div>` with the following CSS:

```css
.some-div{
   position: relative;
   top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-div">
   <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

How do I get the CSS property `position` of the element with JavaScript (which in this example should result in the string `"relative"`)?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/7982963

Comment: If you are simply trying to get an element's position with JavaScript, it's already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Comment: @MoaazBhnas They are asking about the `position` CSS property value, `"relative"` in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain

```
const element = document.getElementById('your_element_id');
const computedStyles = getComputedStyle(element);
const position = computedStyles.position;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "class" has only one element:

***HTML***

```
<div class="some-div"">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
    let someDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('some-div')[0];
    someDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(this.getComputedStyle(someDiv).getPropertyValue('position'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var element = document.querySelector('.some-div');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var pos = style.position;
    console.log(pos);
```

Try this.
The Console output must be: "relative"